# Lasso regression only predicts order of model correctly when poly() is set raw = TRUE?

Tags: r, regression, lasso

I'm looking at exercise 8 in chapter 6 of [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf) and have noticed that the ability of `glmnet()` to correctly identify the non-zero coefficients of a simulated data set depends on whether `poly()` has been set `raw = true` or `raw = false`.

Below I generate sample and construct a model of response variable `y` to depend only on term `x^7`.

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(1)
epsilon <- rnorm(n = 100)
x <- rnorm(n = 100)
y <- 1 + 7*x^7 + epsilon
df <- data.frame(x = x, y =y)

xmat <- model.matrix(y ~ poly(x, degree = 10, raw = FALSE), data = df)[, -1]
cv <- cv.glmnet(xmat, y, alpha = 1)
bestlam <- cv$lambda.min

predict(cv, type = 'coefficients', s = bestlam)
```

When this is run, it shows that the best model determined by cross-validation uses all polynomials to order 7, but when `raw` is changed to `TRUE` it successfully identifies that x^7 is the only predictor that should be in the model.

I thought that this would have something to do with the orthogonality implemented when `raw = FALSE`, but I had understood that using an orthogonal basis can help linear regression perform better not worse!

Any insight into the difference between the two outputs would be much appreciated!

Comment: This has something to do with how *y* is generated. Note that $x^7$ is equal to `poly(x, degree = 7, raw = TRUE) %*% c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`. Generate data with `raw = FALSE` and try the lasso again.